# io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated

Tags: java, grpc

Please help me
I am a beginner in GRPC
When I use the grpc-java, write a demo and find that when I start a A bidirectional streaming RPC, server side!Use client access
The software in your host aborts an established connection
but But I used it on the server side  server.awaitTermination();

11:41:49  io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated
: Transport failed

Comment: Please help me!This is a big trouble for me

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`ManagedChannel.shutdown()`](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.html#shutdown--) on the client side when you are done with the connection.  This initiates an orderly shutdown which prevents the server from thinking the connection ended abruptly.  You can call [`ManagedChannel.awaitTermination()`](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to make sure it has shutdown correctly.

If you don't care about existing RPCs, you can also call `shutdownNow` which forcefully ends all RPCs.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a tutorial from YRRHelp on this [YouTube Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLI5t0u6ye3FGXJMh5kU2RvN0xrul67p7R%5D) (Remove %5D from end of URL). On video 6/6, I came across this error.

As I already have `ManagedChannel` declared as `channel`, I can use `channel.shutdown();`.

See my example below:

```
package grpcClient;

import com.yrrhelp.grpc.userGrpc;
import com.yrrhelp.grpc.User.APIResponse;
import com.yrrhelp.grpc.User.LoginRequest;
import com.yrrhelp.grpc.userGrpc.userBlockingStub;

import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;

public class GrpcClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // forAddress(name, port)
        ManagedChannel channel = 
                ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 9090)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
        
        // stubs to call API - generate from proto files
        // newBlockingStub = will wait for response
        // newStub = will not wait for response
        userBlockingStub userStub = userGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
        
        LoginRequest loginRequest =
                LoginRequest.newBuilder()
                .setUsername("RAM")
                .setPassword("RAM")
                .build();
        
        APIResponse response = userStub.login(loginRequest);
        
        System.out.println(response.getResponsemessage());
        
        channel.shutdown();
    }

}
```